# set default option in a select via ng-init on VALUE and not INDEX

Tags: angularjs

I'm displaying a select dialog like this:

```
<select ng-model="myFormData.theList" ng-options="list.listName for list in myList track by list.listValue">
```

which outputs something like this:

```
<option value="abc">list name 1</option>
<option value="def">list name 2</option>
<option value="ghi">list name 3</option>
<option value="jkl">list name 4</option>
```

and I know I can have a default selection via the array INDEX by adding a ng-init to my select like this:

```
<select ng-model="myFormData.theList" ng-init="myFormData.theList = myList[1]" ng-options="list.listName for list in myList track by list.listValue">
```

how do I set the default selection by **list.listValue**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a function on your scope that takes the value and returns the index:

```
scope.getIndexFromValue = function(value) {
    for(var i=0; i<scope.list.length; i++) {
        if(scope.list[i].listValue === value)
             return i;
    }
};
```

then call it from the ng-init markup:

```
<select ng-model="myFormData.theList" ng-init="myFormData.theList = myList[getIndexFromValue('abc')]" ng-options="list.listName for list in myList track by list.listValue">
```

Comment: This worked... I should have known this. Thanks, @Fordio - I feel like such a bumbling idiot while coding with Angular...

Comment: Hey, we all go through this : http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2439-my-experience-with-angularjs-the-super-heroic-javascript-mvw-framework.htm

Answer (score 2):

Another option besides setting a function is to format the searched value from *ng-init* as a hash with the same attribute used by *track by*:

```
   <select
     ng-init="myFormData.theList = { listValue: 'ghi'}"
     ng-model="myFormData.theList" 
     ng-options="list.listName for list in myList track by list.listValue">
  </select>
```

See the: [Plunker sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/TWCLcECcKtXMrqF8uqWj?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

As per Angular documentation: "ngModel compares by reference, not value. This is important when binding to an array of objects."

The only way I can think to do this would be to iterate through your array and set myFormData.theList equal to the actual object that matches the listValue in your controller when it initializes or when you grab your data via a service call.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ng-model="myFormData.theList" 
    ng-init="myFormData.theList = myList[1].listValue" 
    ng-options="list.listValue as list.listName for list in myList">
```